# Converting a static library .lib to a dynamic library .dll using MinGW windows 7

Tags: c++, c, dll, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Can someone please guide me on how to convert a .lib static library into a .dll file using MinGW on Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot convert that, but you might create a dll using the static .lib and re-export everything.

Comment: Using cygwin, you can do gcc -shared -o library.so -lstatic_library.

Comment: But if the static library is compiled using a different compiler, you are most likely screwed

Comment: @Wimmel
>  you might create a dll using the static .lib and re-export everything
Can you please elaborate this a bit. 
I have successfully converted a static library ".a" to a shared object ".so" on Linux.
Now I want to convert the ".lib" file to a ".dll" for Windows using MinGW

Actually the libraries which I am using are available as static libraries ".a" for Linux and ".lib" for windows. I am just trying to generate shared libraies from these static libs.

Comment: I tested it with [IJG-JPEG library](http://www.ijg.org/) and I needed a [DllMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) simply returning TRUE. `gcc -Wl,-export-all-symbols -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-no-undefined -Wl,--enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc dllmain.c -Wl,-whole-archive jpeg-9a\libjpeg.a  -Wl,-no-whole-archive -shared -o jpeg9a.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.  Rebuild the library as a <s>static</s> dynamic library.

If you don't have the source code, contact the vendor for a <s>static</s> dynamic version of the library.

Comment: Sorry couldn't get you. I have the static library ".lib" available I want to make a .dll out of it.

Comment: My bad, I'll change my answer.